# Running a Mysql query based on result of another mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a page that displays my customers job history but I want to display if the job payment is settled or not.

First the selectedcustID is determined on the page and then I run a query to display all the jobs in a table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE customerID = '$selectedcustID'   ORDER BY date_auto";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++){
  $selectedjobID = mysql_result($result, $i, "jobID");
  $date = mysql_result($result, $i, "date_auto");
  $formatdate =  date("d/m/Y", $date);
  $status = mysql_result($result, $i, "status");
  $notes = mysql_result($result, $i, "notes");

  echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$bgcolor; ......
}
```

The problem is that to get the details of whether the job is invoiced I need to look in another table.

Here are the 2 tables

[image: Tables]

but the jobID per row is determined from the result of the query above.

I've tried running a new query inside the for loop but I can't seem to get it to work.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: How you know that it is PAID? Means, What value you store in paid column?

Comment: Please do NOT use mysql_ functions in php. They are deprecated and a risk in security!

Comment: `Select  jobs.* From jobs left join invoices on jobs.jobsid = invoices.jobid where customerid = ?'... Dont use mysql_* its deprecated instead use pdo that also help for prevent sql injection and queries in loop also slow your app performance

Comment: Use either PDO or mysqli functions. mysql functions are depreciated and a security risk.

Comment: You could get the result using a single SQL query by joining the two tables. How do you know if the job payment is settled? invoiceStatus = ?

Comment: To those saying not to use Mysql, this is a small job database that sits on an internal computer for my family business and is only accessed by 5 family members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the two tables in your SQL query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN invoices ON jobs.jobID=invoices.jobID WHERE jobs.customerID = '$selectedcustID'   ORDER BY date_auto";
```

Comment: Thanks this was perfect.

Comment: Actually looking at it now what I needed was a LEFT JOIN as I needed everything from jobs

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables in your SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.*
FROM jobs a
JOIN invoices b
ON b.jobID = a.jobID
WHERE customerID = '$selectedcustID'
ORDER BY date_auto
```

Be sure to use the mysqli functions. It will take a bit of adjustment, but worth it since the mysql functions are depreciated and not in the current versions of PHP.